# Does i18n support changing language at runtime?

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am currently following this thread: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/495. Based on the comments, i18n does not support changing language at runtime and ngx-translate is a temporary workaround. It also says that ngx-translate will be deprecated as soon as the features are available in i18n.

This thread seems to be dated in 2017 though. But now in 2020, I still cannot find a way to change language at runtime. I can only do it at compile time using commands like the below:

```
ng serve --configuration=es
```

Does anyone have any references on whether it is possible to change language using i18n module at runtime?

Comment: I think the general idea of angulars i18n is to have multiple builds, (for every language) at different slugs. so `www.myapp.com/es/` and `www.myapp.com/en/`. Because as far as I know, the translations will be compiled into the result, so you loose any original translations keys. It is also in one of the answers of a core member of the i18n team in your linked post.